# On iOS 10, didReceiveRemoteNotification method not getting fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios10

On iOS 10, didReceiveRemoteNotification method not getting fired when the user launch the app by tapping on push notification. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to do for ios 10.0

```
import UserNotifications
   // didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
            // do nothing for now
        })
    }
```

Add extension

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    // When app is killed and or in background tapping on this will resut this event
    let payload = Payload(dict: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    triggerThePaylod(payload)
}
```

}

i hope it will help you